# What is the vmssCSE extension in my managed cluster VirtualMachineScaleSet?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I created a managed cluster with two VirtualMachineScaleSet agent pools. Now I am trying to install a CustomScript extension to the VMSS and it fails as there is already an extension installed.

```
{
  "name": "vmssCSE",
  "properties": {
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
    "type": "CustomScript",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
    "settings": {}
  }
}
```

What does this extension do? Obviously it has no settings. Is it safe to delete it? How can I prevent it from being created on cluster creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Azure Kubernetes Service, it's a managed service in Azure and managed by Azure. No matter the VirtualMachine agent or the VirtualMachineScaleSet agent, it's not recommended to manually change the IaaS resources of it. It shows in the Azure AKS [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-use-custom-vm-extensions):

> **Can I use custom VM extensions?**
>
> No. AKS is a managed service, and
> manipulation of the IaaS resources is not supported. To install custom
> components, etc. please leverage the kubernetes APIs and mechanisms.
> For example, leverage DaemonSets to install required components.

The existing extensions are installed by Azure in the creation time to configure the VM or VMSS as the nodes in the AKS cluster. So it's not safe to delete them.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask where you got this from?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst Yes, the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-use-custom-vm-extensions) here. And if it's helpful for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: We wanted to leverage the CSE to send reboot events (in case the node pool scales up/down) to an event grid. We want to be able to handle the cluster in case of a scaling event.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst The autoscale is an auto event and it according to the requirement of your deployment. If think you can create a listener as deployment in the AKS to detect the event. Or if you want to manage the Kubernetes cluster ndoes yourself, I will recommend the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine).